# How do I accomplish concurrent, thread safe access to a list?

Tags: c#, multithreading

What if I've got an object reference in a safe way within a lock, when outside the lock begun to use it without syncronization? Imaging the other threads can NOT use this object after lock release. Would it be guaranteed I would have no stale or cached in processor data? Would I see all the changes other threads made before I've got the lock? Generally, whould it be thread safe?

Let me show some code.

```
private List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
private List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
private List<string> list;
private bool flagList;

private readonly object locker = new object();

// in constructor
list = list1;
flagList = true;

public void Write(string data)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        list.Add(data);
    }
}

// guaranteed non-reentrant code
private void TimerElapsed(object obj)
{
    List<string> l;
    lock (locker)
    {
        l = list;
        list = (flagList) ? list2 : list1;
        flagList = !flagList;
    }
    // process l Count/items here, then clear
    ...
    l.Clear();
    // restart timer
}
```

So, `TimerElapsed` is guaranteed to run only once a time, and `Write` could be called by multiple different threads at any time. The question is: would I always see with `l` all additions being made since previous `TimerElapsed`?

Answer (score 0):

So if that is your question, `Write` will not add any items while the you are within the block of the lock statement in `TimerElapsed`.
You can simplify your code though by using only one list.

```
    private List<string> list = new List<string>();

    private readonly object locker = new object();

    public void Write(string data)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            list.Add(data);
        }
    }

    // guaranteed non-reentrant code
    private void TimerElapsed(object obj)
    {
        List<string> copy;
        lock (locker)
        {
            copy = list;
            list = new List<string>();
        }

        // process copy
    }
```

Comment: Sure, that's a valid point. But I ask something different. Would, say, `copy.Count` always reflect actual count number. Or it could be cached in processor's cache and return stale data since previous call.

Comment: `copy` will not get new items after you left the lock in `TimerElapsed`, as `Write` will already add the items to the new list instance. So it will return the number of items that were in `list` the moment the copy was made, which will be all the items the calls to `Write` since a previous `TimerElapsed` call created that instance.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `l.Clear()` and your other processing occurs after you have released the lock. That means that by the time `l.Clear()` is executed, another thread could have acquired the lock and started executing code.

Since you've released the lock, while you're processing another thread could call `Write`. The timer could elapse again and another thread could acquire the lock, get a reference to the same list, and start processing it. This could happen multiple times. (You don't want to make any assumptions about the length of the timer interval vs. how long it takes to process.)

Instead of making access to the `List` thread safe, what you really need is for the collection itself to be thread safe. Otherwise, as you said, any other thread that obtained a reference "safely" can then do whatever it wants with that object, whenever it wants.

One solution is to use `ConcurrentQueue`. This allows you to safely insert and remove on separate threads, and it handles the locking internally for you.

```
public class UsesConcurrentQueue
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    public void Write(string data)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(data);
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object obj)
    {
        string dataToProcess = null;
        while(_queue.TryDequeue(out dataToProcess))
        {
            // process each string;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you add an item into the queue you don't have to care whether another thread is reading from the same queue.

When the timer elapses and you start processing, you'll keep processing until the queue is empty. You could keep adding items to the queue while you're processing and it would be okay.

If you need to ensure that you don't process the queue on two threads (suppose the timer elapses again before you finish processing the first time) then you could just stop the timer when you enter that method and restart it when you exit.

Or suppose you've got some reason why you want to process a list of items instead of processing them one at a time, like you're processing them as a batch. Then you could do this:

```
    private void TimerElapsed(object obj)
    {
        string dataToProcess = null;
        var list = new List<string>();
        while (_queue.TryDequeue(out dataToProcess))
        {
            list.Add(dataToProcess);
        }
        // Now you've got a list.
    }
```

Now you've got a `List` of items, but it's a local variable, not a class-level field. So you can operate on it, even send it to another method, without having to worry that some other thread is going to modify it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have to mention that timer can't elapse again before previous one finish it's job.  That's just how I start and restart it. I state that only as comment - that's non-reentrant code. What I want to achive is to minimize `Write` execution time. So I would prefer not to use concurrent query as it could slow `Add`. And full list copy could also create unnecessary memory pressure, 'cause list could grow into a big one. So the question is not how to do the same as in written code, but is the written code correct/thread safe.